# Unable to get a non-model field in the validated_data of a Django Rest Framework serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an ItemCollection and Items in my Django models and I want to be able to remove Items from the collection through the UI. In a REST PUT request I add an extra boolean field `deleted` for each Item to signal that an Item should be deleted.

The correct way to handle this seems to be in the `update` method of the Serializer. 
My problem is that this non-model `deleted` field gets removed during validation, so it is not available anymore. Adding `deleted` as a `SerializerMethodField` did not help. For now I get my `deleted` information from the `initial_data` attribute of the Serializer, but that does not feel right.

My current example code is below. Does anybody know a better approach?

Models:

```
    class ItemCollection(models.Model):
        description = models.CharField(max_length=256)


    class Item(models.Model):
        collection = models.ForeignKey(ItemCollection, related_name="items")
```

Serializers:

```
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
    from rest_framework.views import APIView
    from rest_framework.response import Response
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from models import Item, ItemCollection


    class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = Item


    class ItemCollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        items = ItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

        class Meta:
            model = ItemCollection

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            instance.description = validated_data['description']
            for item, item_obj in zip(
                   self.initial_data['items'], validated_data['items']):
                if item['delete']:
                    instance.items.filter(id=item['id']).delete()
            return instance


    class ItemCollectionView(APIView):

        def get(self, request, ic_id):
            item_collection = get_object_or_404(ItemCollection, pk=ic_id)
            serialized = ItemCollectionSerializer(item_collection).data
            return Response(serialized)

        def put(self, request, ic_id):
            item_collection = get_object_or_404(ItemCollection, pk=ic_id)
            serializer = ItemCollectionSerializer(
               item_collection, data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

And an example of the json in the PUT request:

```
    {
        "id": 2,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "collection": 2,
                "delete": true
            }
        ],
        "description": "mycoll"
    }
```

Comment: Would it be acceptable to just do a separate HTTP `DELETE` for each of the nested modules that need deleting?  If you were to use `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer` as your serializers' base class, each sub-item would have a URL that you could easily `DELETE`.

Comment: That's an interesting angle to explore. Although, the main problem is that information about which Items need to be deleted is missing in `validated_data`.

Comment: What I mean is that on the client side, instead of setting flag `delete` on the sub-item, just do an HTTP `DELETE` to that object and remove it from the container.  You don't do the `DELETE` from inside Django ( If I may presume you were insinuating that approach.)

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Nice approach, tx!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can add non-model fields back by overwriting the `to_internal_value` fn:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    internal_value = super(MySerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
    my_non_model_field_raw_value = data.get("my_non_model_field")
    my_non_model_field_value = ConvertRawValueInSomeCleverWay(my_non_model_field_raw_value)
    internal_value.update({
        "my_non_model_field": my_non_model_field_value
    })
    return internal_value
```

Then you can process it however you want in `create` or `update`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a PUT request, your view is probably calling `self.perform_update(serializer)`. Change it for

```
serializer.save(<my_non_model_field>=request.data.get('<my_non_model_field>', <default_value>)
```

All `kwargs` are passed down to validated_data to your serializer.
Make sure to properly transform incoming value (to boolean, to int, etc.)