# Serializer validated_data is empty even when is_valid is True

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Following code returning an empty json.

```
def create_account(request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data={'name': request.GET.get('name'), 'surname': request.GET.get('surname'),
                                      'password': request.GET.get('password'), 'email': request.GET.get('email')})
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        return HttpResponse(status=401,content=serializer.errors)

    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

And this is my serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'surname', 'password', 'email')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

When i send a request, `serializer.initial_data` is filled correctly. `is_valid` is returning `True` but `validated_data` is empty.

Comment: Does the user object being saved?

Comment: Try tracing these lines with pdb while running the code https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L193

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like you're using a custom User model and django.contrib.auth.models.User doesn't have the name and surname fields. It does however have first_name and last_name. Try using those as fields in your serializer instead since they are model fields. Otherwise you'll have to override to_internal_value as this answer suggests.

[Unable to get a non-model field in the validated_data of a Django Rest Framework serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665220/unable-to-get-a-non-model-field-in-the-validated-data-of-a-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I used `serializers.Serializer` instead of `serializers.ModelSerializer` after I changed it to `ModelSerializer`, it solved.